# Python data manipulation to delete rows based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, multiple-conditions

I have three columns, one with different Text, another column represents the category they belong to, third column is the department

Example

```
department Category  Text

1          a7        great school
1          a7        Enjoy classes
1          a7        Social studies
1          a8        JOHN
1          a8        RONIE
1          a8        Amazing lecturer
1          a8        walking to school
1          a9        Effective tomorrow
1          a9        marie kate
1          a9        math
2          a8        lissie
2          a8        lovely
2          a5        Ronie
```

If any Text in the category contains JOHN, the entire category has to be removed.
For example, since There JOHN is in category a8 for department1, all rows of the category a8 has to be removed for department 1 alone. Since there is no JOHN in category a8 of department 2, nothing needs to be done here

```
indexNames = df[(df['Text'] == 'JOHN').index
```

desired output:

```
 department Category  Text
    1          a7        great school    
    1          a7        Enjoy classes    
    1          a7        Social studies    
    1          a9        Effective tomorrow    
    1          a9        marie kate    
    1          a9        math    
    2          a8        lissie    
    2          a8        lovely    
    2          a5        Ronie
```

I am new to python. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Adding the desired output would help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is harder than it looks at the first glance :)

First, find the categories and departments to be removed:

```
to_be_removed = df.loc[df.Text == 'JOHN', ['department', 'Category']]
```

Next, select all rows that are in those categories by merging the original data frame and the one obtained at the previous step. We need only the indexes of those rows:

```
bad_indexes = df.reset_index().merge(to_be_removed)['index']
```

Finally, extract the "good" rows:

```
df.loc[~df.index.isin(bad_indexes)]

#    department Category                Text
#0            1       a7        great school
#1            1       a7       Enjoy classes
#2            1       a7      Social studies
#7            1       a9  Effective tomorrow
#8            1       a9          marie kate
#9            1       a9                math
#10           2       a8              lissie
#11           2       a8              lovely
#12           2       a5               Ronie
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can filter `df` as such:

1. Get the departments that have 'JOHN' as the Text value
2. Filter out the records that are have department in the list from (1) above

```
tmp = df[(df['Text'] == 'JOHN')] 

df = df[~(df['Category'].isin(tmp['Category']))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this question is for pandas. If you are not using pandas, try pandas.I created the dataframe using below codes in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['department']=department
df['category']=category
df['text']=text
```

You can remove the rows from dataframe by specifying the column and the condition as shown below.

```
cdn1 = df['text']=='JOHN'
cdn2 = df['category'] == df.loc[cdn1]['category'].values[0]
cdn3 = df['department'] == df.loc[cdn1]['department'].values[0]
```

Then drop the corresponding indexes

```
df.drop(np.where(cdn2 & cdn3)[0], inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
department  category    text
    1           a7          great school
    1           a7          Enjoy classes
    1           a7          Social studies
    1           a9          Effective tomorrow
    1           a9          marie kate
    1           a9          math
    2           a8          lissie
    2           a8          lovely
    2           a5          Ronie
```

Comment: We should not remove all a8 rows. Thats what the question states. Only the rows corresponding to JOHN has to be removed

Comment: Not true. The OP says: "__all rows of the category a8__ has to be removed for department 1 alone."

Comment: "for department 1 alone."

Comment: It says " for department one alone" .read further and it says "Since there is no JOHN in category a8 or department 2, nothing needs to be done here"